# SQL: Left join on calendar table (spark SQL)

Tags: sql, join, apache-spark-sql, left-join, many-to-one

I am trying to join data to a calendar table cross joined with user id, to get other columns corresponding to it. I have tried joining on date condition, without the date condition. Created a cross joined master table to left join the other data on. However, seems like I am missing something.

DATE_TBL looks like:

```
CAL_DT  BUYER_ID
2019-03-31  1
2019-03-31  2
2019-03-31  3
2019-03-30  1
2019-03-30  2
2019-03-30  3
2019-03-29  1
2019-03-29  2
2019-03-29  3 ......
```

DATA2 looks like:

```
CREATED_DT  BUYER_ID ITEM_PRICE
2019-03-31  1   10
2019-03-30  2.  12
2019-03-29  3.  45
2019-03-29  2.  13 ........
```

Here is my code:

```
WITH DATE_TBL AS
(
SELECT CAL.CAL_DT, CK.BUYER_ID
FROM DATA1 CAL
CROSS JOIN DATA2 CK
WHERE cal.CAL_DT BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-03-31'
AND CK.BYR_CNTRY_ID IN (1,2,3) AND CK.CREATED_DT BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
GROUP BY 1,2
)
,
REVENUE_CALC AS 
(
SELECT CAL.CAL_DT
      ,CK.BYR_CNTRY_ID
      ,CK.BUYER_ID
      ,CK.CREATED_DT AS CREATED_DT
      ,SUM(CK.ITEM_PRICE) AS ITEM_PRICE
      ,SUM(CK.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
      ,MAX(COALESCE(I.CURNCY_PLAN_RATE, 1)) AS CURNCY_PLAN_RATE
      
      ,SUM(CK.ITEM_PRICE *CK.QUANTITY *I.CURNCY_PLAN_RATE) AS REVENUE

      FROM DATE_TBL CAL
      LEFT JOIN DATA2 CK
      ON CAL.BUYER_ID = CK.BUYER_ID AND CAL.CAL_DT = CK.CREATED_DT
      
      LEFT JOIN DATA3 I
      ON I.CURNCY_ID   = CK.LSTG_CURNCY_ID
      
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
      ORDER BY CAL.CAL_DT DESC, CK.BUYER_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM REVENUE_CALC
```

Desired Result Must look like:

```
CAL_DT  BUYER_ID ITEM ITEM_PRICE
2019-03-31  1.    10
2019-03-31  2.    null
2019-03-31  3.    null
2019-03-30  1.    null
2019-03-30  2.    12
2019-03-30  3.    null
2019-03-29  1.    null
2019-03-29  2.    13
2019-03-29  3.    45......
```

What I get is only the data for common dates. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sample data and desired output would help

Comment: Your filter on `Buyer_ID` is going to turn the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not sure where are you referring to here